# Converting Windows 2012 R2 from Hyper-V to KVM (qemu)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, kvm-virtualization

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 running SharePoint 2013 which I am trying to migrate from Hyper-V to KVM (qemu). I have converted the vhdx file to qcow2 format 
and copied it across to the KVM server (RHEL 7.3)

The Hyper-V VM was configured as Generation 2 and I have create a new VM in KVM with a UEFI firmware (OVMF).

When I boot up the machine goes in to Automatic Repair mode but will not boot. I can open the Cmd Prompt and to do so I need to authenticate with the local Administrator password.

I have run the following:

1. Type BOOTREC /FIXMBR, and then press ENTER.
2. Type BOOTREC /FIXBOOT, and then press ENTER.
3. Type Drive:\boot\Bootsect.exe /NT60 All, and then press ENTER.

However the VM is unable to boot always enters Repair mode.

Any suggestions on what I might need to check or any 3rd party utilities I might be able to use or buy to help me easily get past this ?

If I login to command prompt I can run Diskpart / sel disk 0 / list vol to see :

```
Volume 0    D          CDROM          0 B   No Media
Volume 1    C NTFS     Partition    126GB   Healthy
Volume 2    E Recovery Partition    300MB   Healthy   Hidden
Volume 3               Partition     99MB   Healthy   Hidden
```

VM on KVM was configured as:

*Emulator:/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm
*Firmware:UEFI x86_64:
*/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_CODE-pure-efi.fd 
*CPUs 8 
*Memory 8192MB 
*IDE DISK- Disk Bus IDE 
*Storage format qcow2

What I have done so far:

1. Opened Hyper-V and Exported the VM to a new directory on Windows
2. Use Hyper-V Inspect Disk to merge the difference avhdx and vhdx disks into one vhdx
3. Used StarWind v2v Converter to create a qcow2 file
4. Copied the qcows file to KVM machine
5. Create new VM of same spec:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
6. When starting the new machine I see this:

[image]

Comment: Was EFI boot used on VM under Hyper-V server?

Comment: EFI was used on VM under Hyper-V

Comment: One obvious thing I see is that Chipset should be set to Q35 (not i440fx) if you intend to use UEFI.

Comment: Good spot - I wasn't aware of this alternative. Tried to set the q35 in the xml file using virsh edit however virsh complained about validation on exit and would not save.

Comment: Any help on how to get q35 architecture as a configurable option in virt-manager ?

Comment: Not sure the Q35 architecture is responsible here. Seems as though it offers an improved architecture but notes I have read appear to say that it has been removed from centos7/redhat7 KVM distributions on purpose and there should no impact on being able to run windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This this

```
yum install qemu-img
```

First, check the file, make sure it’s ok.

```
qemu-img check -r all rmcjmc01.vhdx
```

If ok, convert the file

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 rmcgmc01.vhdx rmcgmc01.qcow2
```

Comment: I tried this however I get an error so decided to use StarWind v2v Converter instead

Comment: Original Post has been updated to include more detail

Comment: I tried this approach again (still struggling here) with a new test Windows 2012 R2 Vm and this time there seems to be more progress than with the StarWind V2V Converter. The VM does not boot however the blue Windows Troubleshooting starts. One option is Refresh Your PC however this can't proceed since I get a message saying "The Drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the Drive and try again."

Comment: Ended up working out using qemu-img. Not sure why StarWind converter didn't work.

Answer (score 19):

What's your tool for converting? MVMC? You can also try StarWind v2v converter: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter It was a big help at my time. And besides, it makes identical hard drive when converts from Hyper-v. Conversion itself is performing at the block level, so all the blocks should be copied unchanged.

Comment: Also using StarWind v2v Converter.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to use StarWind v2v Converter. Qemu-img convert stuck at 0%, cpu 100% for the whole night. StartWind was done in less than an hour.